# Как программно экранировать управляющие символы в строке?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, c#-7.0

Мне необходимо вставить в паттерн регулярного выражения:

```
$@"^(?:[^\p{{L}}]|[{exclusion}])+$" //Цель: Запретить использование каких либо букв в строке, кроме тех что заданы в переменной - exclusion
```

строковую переменную:

```
string exclusion;
```

в которой все управляющие символы были бы экранированы, что позволило бы избежать ошибок связанных с работой регулярного выражения.

Я нашел метод `Regex.Escape()`. Но он не удовлетворяет моим потребностям. Например, если значение `exclusion = @"[text]"` передать в метод `Regex.Escape()` то он вернет строку `"\\[text]"`. После вставки данной строки в паттерн вместо переменно exclusion:

```
$@"^(?:[^\p{{L}}]|[{exclusion}])+$" //Цель: запретить использование каких либо букв в строке, кроме тех что заданы в переменной - exclusion
```

он приобретает следующий вид:

```
$@"^(?:[^\p{{L}}]|[\[text]])+$"
```

В результате регулярное выражение работает неправильно. Подозреваю, что причина в лишнем символе - `]`

Скажите пожалуйста как экранировать все управляющие символы в строке? Есть ли какой то другой способ кроме метода - Regex.Escape()? Может быть я его как то неправильно использовал и не замечаю своей ошибки?

Comment: проблема скорее в `@`

Comment: @Grundy Я попробовал удалить символ @ стоящий в начале регулярного выражения: $"^(?:[^\\p{{L}}]|[{exclusion}])+$", данное решение не помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: а ты уверен что не помогло? ты пробовал прописывать напрямую без переменной? поведение регулярки менялось? Возможно просто регулярное выражение неверное

Comment: @Grundy Уверен. Как только я убираю из переменной - exclusion квадратные скобки, регулярное выражение работает нормально. Также, я пробовал напрямую, без переменной, подставлять какие либо тестовые символы вместо переменной. В итоге, все работает. Например: ^(?:[^\p{Lu}]|[ABC])+$ (работает), ^(?:[^\p{Lu}]|[\\[ABC]])+$ (после экранирования Regex.Escape, не работает), ^(?:[^\p{Lu}]|[\\[ABC\\]])+$ (при выполнении экранирования руками обоих скобок все работает) Похоже, все указывает на то что проблема в квадратных скобках, а именно в том, что метод Regex.Escape() экранирует только одну из них.

Comment: У тебя неверная регулярка: вот так делать неправильно `[[ABC]]`

Comment: У вас в части "приобретает следующий вид" неправильно строка указана - там \ лишний. На самом деле у вас строка `@"^(?:[^\p{L}]|[\[text]])+$". Но да, глючит из-за скобки

Comment: @Grundy у него правильная регулярка - он хочет собрать Positive Character Group из букв t e s t и двух скобок.

Comment: Regex.Escape не расчитан на использование его результата внути Character Group. Дозаменяйте руками через `.Replace("]", @"\]")`

Comment: @Grundy по поводу [[ABC]], Здесь я просто смоделировал ситуацию, связанную с тему, что в строчную переменную exclusion может попасть строка вида "[ABC]". Для того, чтобы решить проблему я использовал Regex.Escape(), но это не помогло. Судя по всему из за того, что метод экранирует только первую квадратную скобку.

Comment: @PashaPash Да, похоже что вы правы. Хмм, не понятно , почему Regex.Escape() экранирует только одну из двух кавычек.

Comment: @PashaPash Ошибку исправил.

Comment: @PashaPash, а разве скобки внутри скобок не надо экранировать?

Comment: @Grundy, Evgeniy Miroshnichenko скобки внутри скобок надо экранировать, вот только Regex.Escape написан из расчета, что его результат будет использован для прямого поиска экранированной строки, а не как набор символов внутри character group. Поэтому он экранирует . $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \, но не ] и } - т.к. эти закрывающие скобки не попадают в список спецсимволов (тех, которые не матчатся сами на себя) - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @Grundy это примерно как ^ - это не спецсимвол, он не требует экранирования, но внезапно его нельзя поставить просто так первым в character group ([^...]).Со скобкой ] то же самое - она не требует экранирования, но ее нельзя просто так поставить внутри character group

Comment: @PashaPash, ну тогда ж получается что `[[]]` нельзя написать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Regex.Escape`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2) экранирует те знаки, которые считаются специальными вне символьных классов:

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#`, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. (*Экранирует минимальный набор знаков (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#` и пробельный символ) путём замены на их escape-коды*)

На самом деле, внутри символьных классов специальными считаются только следующие символы:

- `^` - может означать исклбчающий тип символьного класса, если находится сразу после открывающей `[`
- `]` - закрывает символьный класс
- `\` - экранирует специальные символы
- `-` - задаёт диапазон символов или "вычитание символьных классов"

Для экранирования этих знаков достаточно использовать

```
exclusion.Replace("\\", @"\\").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("]", @"\]")
```

или

```
Regex.Replace(exclusion, @"[]^\\-]", "\\$&")
```

Решение:

```
var pattern = $@"^(?:[^\p{{L}}]|[{Regex.Replace(exclusion, @"[]^\\-]", "\\$&")}])+$";
```

Или (так как `[^\p{L}]` = `\P{L}`):

```
var pattern2 = $@"^[\P{{L}}{Regex.Replace(exclusion, @"[]^\\-]", "\\$&")}]+$";
```